# Exception when trying to use HttpListener in UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, httplistener

I'm trying to build an UWP and instantiate `HttpListener`. However, I'm getting the following error in Visual Studio's Error List: `Cannot find type System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketContext in module System.Net.WebSockets.dll`, preventing me from building and running the application.

My application looks as follows:

```
using System.Net;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace HttpTestServer
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
        }

        private static void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var httpListener = new HttpListener();
            httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:9080/");
            httpListener.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

I believe it's related the minimum Windows version I'm targeting. I'm forced to target *Windows 10 Anniversary Update build 10.0.14393.0*. How do I know if `HttpListener` is included in this version of Windows? According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=netframework-4.8 it should be included in .NET Standard 2.0.

Is it possible to instantiate the `HttpListener` somehow anyways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I know if HttpListener is included in this version of Windows?

Derive from official document `HttpListener` included in [.Net Standard 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support), and the lowest UWP version that support .Net Standard 2.0 is 16299 (Fall Creators Update), So the you need edit the app's target min version to 16299.